# nginX matching path after host

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to implement the following rule:

```
location ~ ^/stylesheets|javascripts|assets/
```

However it's matching against:

```
mysite.com/something/something/javascripts
```

My thought was this simple regex would only match.

```
mysite.com/javascripts
```

I want it to ignore nesting, what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your whole set of location rules please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to group the OR'ed expression: `^/(stylesheets|javascripts|assets)/`

Otherwise you'd have three slightly different potential matches:

1. Any path starting with `/stylesheets`,
2. Any path containing `javascripts` somewhere and
3. Any path containing `assets/` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was missing.